# aws s3 sync cli ignoring multipart upload config when syncing between buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to sync a large number of files from one bucket to another, some of the files are up to 2GB in size after using the aws cli's s3 sync command like so

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/folder/folder s3://destination-bucket/folder/folder
```

and verifying the files that had been transferred it became clear that the large files had lost the metadata that was present on the original file in the original bucket.

This is a "known" issue with larger files where s3 switches to multipart upload to handled the transfer.
This multipart handeling can be configured via the .aws/config file which has been done like so

```
[default]
s3 =
    multipart_threshold = 4500MB
```

However when again testing the transfer the metadata on the larger files is still not present, it is present on any of the smaller files so it's clear that I'm heating the multipart upload issue.

Given this is an s3 to s3 transfer is the local s3 configuration taken into consideration at all?
As an alternative to this is there a way to just sync the metadata now that all the files have been transferred?

Have also tried doing `aws s3 cp` with no luck either.

Comment: Is this a one-off desire, or do you wish to keep the contents of the two buckets in sync on a continuous basis?

Comment: It's a one off transfer for these items - though something we'll repeat for other items in the future.  

There are thousands of objects that we're looking to shift at the moment which is why I'm hoping to use s3 sync or s3 copy. The metadata on the files is also important as it's from a 3rd party backup tool and without it the files are useless.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Cross/Same-Region Replication** to copy the objects to another Amazon S3 bucket.

However, only *newly added* objects will copy between the buckets. You can, however, trigger the copy by **copying the objects onto themselves**. I'd recommend you test this on a separate bucket first, to make sure you don't accidentally lose any of the metadata.

The method suggested seems rather complex: [Trigger cross-region replication of pre-existing objects using Amazon S3 inventory, Amazon EMR, and Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/trigger-cross-region-replication-of-pre-existing-objects-using-amazon-s3-inventory-amazon-emr-and-amazon-athena/)

The final option would be to **write your own code to copy the objects**, and copy the metadata at the same time.

Or, you could write a script that **compares the two buckets to see which objects did *not* get their correct metadata, and have it just update the metadata** on the target object. This actually involves copying the object to itself, while specifying the metadata. This is probably easier than copying *ALL* objects yourself, since it only needs to 'fix' the ones that didn't get their metadata.

Comment: Thanks John - the final option sounds the safest. use s3 sync to shift all the objects then write something to trawl through the destination and find all objects with missing metadata, retrieve the values from the source and update.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to implement a solution for this and took the oportunity to play around with the Serverless framework and Step Functions.

The general flow I went with was:

- Step Function triggered using a Cloudwatch Event Rule targetting S3 Events of the type 'CompleteMultipartUpload', as the metadata is only ever missing on S3 objects that had to be transfered using a multipart process
- The initial Task on the Step Function checks if all the required MetaData is present on the object that raised the event.

  - If it is present then the Step Function is finished
  - If it is not present then the second lambda task is fired which copies all metadata from the source object to the destination object.

This could be achieved without Step Functions however was a good simple exercise to give them a go. The first 'Check Meta' task is actually redundant as the metadata is never present if multipart transfer is used, I was originally also triggering off of PutObject and CopyObject as well which is why I had the Check Meta task.